# Lebesgue integral of a strange function.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

The problem statement is as follows: 
Let $f: [0, 2]\to \mathbb R_{+}$ be defined by
$f(t)=m(\{x\in [0, \pi]: t\leq 1+\cos (3x)\leq 3t\}).$ Compute $\int_0^2 f(t)\,dt$.

I'm not certain how to begin understanding this function other than solving the inequality and finding lengths of resulting solution intervals. This doesn't seem to lead to any nice pattern. Is there a fundamental theorem for Lebesgue integrals? What should I do?

Comment: Use Fubini's Theorem. Turn $f(t)$ into an integral of a characteristic function then reverse the order of integration, since everything is positive.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't see an underlying product space, how does Fubinin's Theorem apply?

Comment: You can write $f(t)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\chi_{t\leq 1+\cos(3x)\leq 3t}\ dx$, where the integral is w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on $[0,\pi]$. Then you have a double integral over the product space $[0,2]\times[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

By Fubini-Tonelli, we can interchange the order of integration as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 f(t)\mathsf dt &= \int_0^2 m(\{x\in[0,\pi]: t\leqslant 1 + \cos(3x) \leqslant 3t\} \mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^2 \int_0^\pi \chi_{\{t\leqslant 1 + \cos 3x\leqslant 3t\}}(x)\mathsf dx\,\mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^\pi \int_0^2 \chi_{\{t\leqslant 1 + \cos 3x\leqslant 3t\}}(t)\mathsf dt\,\mathsf dx.
\end{align*}$$
Now, we have $0\leqslant t\leqslant 2$ and $t\leqslant 1+\cos3x\leqslant 3t$. Since $0\leqslant 1+\cos3x\leqslant2$ for any $x$, this is equivalent to
$$\frac13(1+\cos3x)\leqslant t \leqslant 1+\cos3x.$$
Hence the integral is equal to
$$
\int_0^\pi\int_{\frac13(1+\cos3x)}^{1+\cos3x}\mathsf dt\,\mathsf dx 
= \int_0^\pi \frac23(1+\cos3x)\mathsf dx = \frac{2\pi}3.
$$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm tired ;)

Comment: Why is $\int_0^2 \chi_{\{t\leqslant 1 + \cos 3x\leqslant 3t\}}(t)\mathsf dt = \int_0^{\frac13\left(1+\cos 3x\right)}\mathsf dt $? Is this simply the nature of the function?

Comment: I messed up the bounds. Let me correct it.

Comment: I messed up the bounds. Let me correct it.

Comment: Sorry, I got the bounds wrong. It should be correct now.